# Irvine32 and MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I would like some help in adding Irvine32 inc/lib support to my asm programs. I added the inc/lib to their folders and added
include Irvine32.inc
includeLib Irvine32.lib
But I get errors when linking with Irvine32.lib.

Is there is a place where I can download an all-in-one package that has the lib working.

Thanks

Comment: Hmya, there's a point where downloading tools or hoping for the all-in-one magic solution stops solving your problems.  You then got only one left, the one between your ears.  Those error messages that you didn't document are supposed to inform that tool, telling it what to do next.  I'm quite sure they don't say "download something else".

Comment: No, it doesn't say download. But I have tried several versions of the lib (from the author website), as well as a couple of versions of MASM. One of them said the library was not correct library file. The last one I tried, the error output is too long to put here, but it is mainly cased from within the library itself, and not the asm program or the way you link it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, that could have turned out better.  You could post your solution and mark it as the answer.  But only if you care a wee bit about avoiding becoming part of the SO belly lint.

Comment: Why did you remove your comment and replace it with this. Go post some useless comments just to be up-voted so that you don't become one of those you mentioned ;)

Answer (score 2):

if you use [masm32](http://www.masm32.com/) program put the Irvine32.inc into masm32\include folder and Irvine32.lib in masm32\lib folder. In source file asm write

```
includelib   \masm32\lib\Irvine32.lib
include      \masm32\include\Irvine32.inc
```

I successed when i was reading this book!

Answer (score 1):

The library you mention is used with Kip Irvine's book, "Assembly Language for x86 Processors".  It's currently in its' sixth edition and I am finding it to be a great intro to assembly.

In the early chapters (chapter 3, I believe), he goes over the include process.  It states where to put files, etc. and may be of some help to you (I'd document it here, but it's a little involved).

Cheers,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo project that comes with the examples for the book, you can use that project as a basis for your project. You should also check your linker settings, and make sure the paths to Irvine32 libraries are included in the additional library dependencies property. I had that issue once and just created a template project using the default project that is shipped Kip's book.

Visit my blog [Setting up vs10 for programming with masm32](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/category/assembly-masm32/) for details on how to add libraries to a masm32 project.