# what's wrong assembly ERROR [undefined symbol]

Tags: assembly, irvine32, masm32

USING MASM32

I don't know what's the error here I tried my best but still having error
i am running it in cmd by masm32
with coff and without and nothing fixed!
so what should I do.

the porpose of the code to find the GCD by entering two integers and then display the GCD value.

here is my code:

***CODE:***

```
 includelib Irvine32.inc
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
intReqStr BYTE "Enter integer: ",0
ansStr BYTE "GCD is: ",0

.code
main PROC
L1:
    mov edx, OFFSET intReqStr ; Display integer request
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    jz QUIT
    mov ebx, eax ; assign to y
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    jz QUIT

    call CalcGCD

    mov edx, OFFSET ansStr
    call WriteString
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    call Crlf
    jmp L1
QUIT:
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP

CalcGCD PROC
    push ebx
    push edx

    cmp eax, 0 ;if x >= 0 jump over negate
    jge LX
    neg eax ; x was negative so negate
LX:
    cmp ebx, 0 ;if x >= 0 jump over negate
    jge LY
    neg ebx ; x was negative so negate
LY:
DO: mov edx, 0
    div ebx ; edx = eax % ebx (n = x & y)
    mov eax, ebx ; eax = ebx (x = y)
    mov ebx, edx ; ebx = edx (y = n)

    cmp ebx, 0  ; while ebx > 0
    jg DO   ; jump to do line
        ; x to be returned is in EAX
    pop edx
    pop ebx
    ret
CalcGCD ENDP

end main
```

***ERROR:***

```
file.asm(15) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
file.asm(16) : error A2006: undefined symbol : ReadInt
file.asm(19) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
file.asm(20) : error A2006: undefined symbol : ReadInt
file.asm(26) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
file.asm(27) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteDec
file.asm(28) : error A2006: undefined symbol : Crlf
file.asm(29) : error A2006: undefined symbol : Crlf
```

*help me :(*

Comment: It looks like the assembler is complaining about the lack of a `.model` directive.  Why is yours commented out?

Comment: @NateEldredge i removed the semicolon its now uncommented but still geting this error `file.asm(15) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
file.asm(16) : error A2006: undefined symbol : ReadInt
file.asm(19) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
file.asm(20) : error A2006: undefined symbol : ReadInt
file.asm(26) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
file.asm(27) : error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteDec
file.asm(28) : error A2006: undefined symbol : Crlf
file.asm(29) : error A2006: undefined symbol : Crlf`

Comment: @MHOM You are calling functions which are not defined in your program, that's why MASM complains. They should be declared as `EXTERN` or the **library** file `Irvine32.lib` included instead of **header** file `Irvine32.inc`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572175/irvine32-and-masm

Comment: @vitsoft: looks like a duplicate, then, and possibly a useful signpost for future searchers since it includes some error messages you get when you leave out the `includelib   \masm32\lib\Irvine32.lib`.  You could have voted to close as duplicate yourself as well as commenting with the link

Comment: @NateEldredge IIRC, the Irvine include-file specifies a model, so OP probably shouldn't specify one of their own when using that library.